# Why WPF introduces a new types for collections?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I found out, that WPF uses internally a lot of collections such as `ItemCollection` or `DataGridCollumnCollection`. Why not use plain old List or array instead?

Comment: Because reasons.

Comment: Because those classes typically implement a lot of specialized interfaces, like e.g. IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem.

Comment: They act like lists though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ItemsCollection` is a great example. It provides grouping and sorting that is accessible from XAML where traditional LINQ is not.

The other classes follow the same pattern. They add features that should not, or cannot be added to the extremely commonly used collection types. Changing the behaviour or performance of `List<T>` would almost always be a breaking API change for somebody.

Most of these classes are implementations of the static [Decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html). Features are added to the existing collection concept, without changing the existing classes. Notice that it inherits and implements the following:

- IList
- ICollection
- IEnumerable

These are the bread and butter interfaces for working with collections of all types. I'd be surprised if ItemsCollection doesn't use `List<object>` as a backing store at some point in the implementation.